# java "this" in c++

Tags: java, c++, this

I'm in a function in java and I create a new Object passing "this" as parameter:

```
class AClass { 
    AClass(TestClass testClass) { }
}

class TestClass {
    AClass doSomething()
    {
        return new AClass(this);
    }
}
```

How to do That in C++?

Should be:

```
class AClass {
    AClass(TestClass* testClass) { }
};

class TestClass {
    AClass* doSomething()
    {
        return new AClass(*this);
    }
};
```

Should I pass *this, or &this?

Comment: You should get [a good introductory book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list) if you don't have one.  Aside from the use of mustaches (sorry, I mean curly braces), C++ is not very similar to Java at all.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. You're probably looking for this:

```
class AClass { 
    AClass(TestClass& testClass) { } 
}; 

class TestClass { 
    AClass doSomething() 
    { 
        return AClass(*this); 
    } 
};
```

To use it in C++:

```
TestClass testClass;
AClass aClass = testClass.doSomething();
```

But what are you really trying to do? Unlike Java, C++ makes the distinction between values and references explicit. You should really [read a good beginner's C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list), as James McNellis has suggested.

The distinction between values/references/pointers that C++ makes is fundamental to the language and failing to respect that will lead to disaster. Again, please pick up a C++ book.

Comment: by this way you're copying the TestClass passing *this? So the constructor is being called like that: AClass(TestClass testClass) { }

but if I put "return &this;" the AClass constructor should be: AClass(TestClass *testClass) { } ?

Comment: Again, that depends, since C++ makes the distinction between values and references explicit. Passing `*this` to `AClass(TestClass testClass)` makes a copy, while passing `*this` to `AClass(TestClass& testClass)` doesn't. That is one of the fundamental differences from Java - I recommend a good C++ book as it is much beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: I want to pass the TestClass as reference

Comment: @okami - I have modified my answer so that a reference to `TestClass` is passed instead of a pointer. But please, I implore you to pick up a C++ book and read it (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list). I don't mean to be offensive, but C++ is very different from Java and treating C++ like Java will not help you in the long run.

Comment: `this` is of type `TestClass *` so doing `AClass(this)` will call `AClass(TestClass *testClass)`.

Comment: @NikiYoshiuchi: I can't believe that you're the only one who gave this correct answer! ('this' is *already* a pointer to TestClass).

Answer (score 0):

Given the declaration you wrote

```
class AClass {
    AClass(TestClass* testClass) { }
};
```

You need to pass a pointer, so you'd use `this`.  However, it's generally preferred in C++ to use references (especially `const` references) instead of pointers, so you'd declare `AClass` as:

```
class AClass {
    AClass(const TestClass& testClass) { }
};
```

To which you would pass `*this`.

Now, there are situations in which the pointer version is preferred.  For example, if `testClass` were allowed to be `NULL` (you can't have null references).  Or if `testClass` were stored in a `std::vector` or similar data structure.  (You can't have arrays of references.)

Comment: very good, const is very useful in c++ much more than java "final"